# Pass multiple arguments from a file to while loop in Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file containing couple of words like :

```
server1 location1
server2 location2
```

I need to pass these in a while loop.

How do we assign them to two separate variables? Something like this may be

```
while read server,location
do
echo $server is in $location
done <file
```

I'm able to work with 1 variable very fine, but couldn't figure out this one.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use space between variables, not comma:

```
while read -r server location
do
echo "${server}" is in "${location}"
done <file
```

Note that first word will be read into `server` and "everything else" will go into `location`. So if your file happens to contain more than two words then you may want to ignore the rest with a *dummy* variable:

```
while read -r server location dummy
do
echo "${server}" is in "${location}"
done <file
```

Comment: Are you able to parse the whole file using `read` without dropping the rest of the line? I think that's what the OP is after.

Comment: I have edited the post to make it clear (you can see from the edit history for what OP meant to ask). It *did* look like what you are saying. But it's a due to poor formatting in the question. Sorry!

Comment: I might be missing something, but I don't see that in the edit history. I see that _you_ have edited the question not the OP???

Comment: @mhawke All I did was *format* those two lines OP had. You have to see the *source* of the history, not just history before accusing me of edting it to *suit* my answer.

Comment: @mhawke Here's the link for you: [source](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5f03f72f-a1c9-43e3-b5fd-dc067e5953b3/view-source). If you still don't believe, flag it to a moderator.

Comment: Hold on to your horses... I already retracted the accusation before you replied... I'm not insinuating anything.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I didn't notice that the source was available.

Comment: @mhawke I see you edited your comment. It was *very* different before. There are polite ways to ask for clarification without resorting to baseless accusations.

Comment: Yeah, sorry again. I edited the comment as soon as I submitted it - I'm surprised that you saw it at all. It was an accident; of course I meant it initially, but I wasn't really sure, and accidentally submitted it whilst editing to what it now is. At least I know now that you can see the source.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit rusty with shell scripting so I doubt that this is the best way, but you can do it like this:

```
set $(cat file)
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    echo $1 is in $2
    shift 2
done
```

Another way is to use `awk`:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) printf "%s is in %s\n", $i, $(i+1);}' file
```